# Advantage Database Error 5175

Tags: c#, .net, indexing, collation, advantage-database-server

I'm trying to read data from an Advantage Database with Advantage .Net Data Provider.
When I execute my app, I have the following error :

> "Error 5175 the index was created with a different collation sequence"

A way to fix it is to open the table with Advantage Data Architect and reindex or delete the index file (.adi) but I can't do this because the database is used by an accounting software (Sage BOB 50) and if I reindex or delete the index, the software is unable to access the data anymore.

Any ideas?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130953/advantage-database-index-collation-sequence

Answer (score 3):

The collation your connection will use depends on the way you are connecting to the server. (See also [Advantage Database Index Collation Sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130953/advantage-database-index-collation-sequence)).

In order to avoid the 5175 error you should use the same connection method that the accounting software uses.

If it uses ALS you can copy the `adslocal.cfg` config file over to your application. If it uses ADS you should make sure that you connect to the same database server that the accounting software does.

Comment: The accounting software uses ALS to connect the database, I copied the `adslocal.cfg` file that was next to the accounting software to my application but that does not solve my problem.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Where is the Advantage .Net provider / adsloc32.dll being pulled from?  You will want to place the adslocal.cfg into this folder.  Might try using processmon to determine where it's trying to pull the adslocal.cfg